# Summing three textboxes into a fourth with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried for ages to find out how to do something which, on the face of it, seems simple.  Basically, I have three textboxes on an Excel userform which hold currency amounts read in from three cells on a worksheet.  I want to sum the contents of the three textboxes into a fourth textbox but, no matter what I try, the best I can achieve is to get the three values concatenated, not added. I have spent many hours trying to solve this without success and have written so many experimental bits of code that I think it will only confuse matters if I show any of it.  Can anyonehelp, please?

Comment: your bits of code will only help us, not confuse us.. please show code snippets only then the SO community can help...

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the numeric value of each text box:

```
textbox4.text = val(textbox1.text) + val(textbox2.text) + val(textbox3.text)
```